# Need help connecting PHP to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a website for a friend and he would like some statistics on the website. The statistics are on a dedicated MySQL server, and the website is on another. I have been trying to keep linking the database to the website but it keeps failing. I am using PHP to attempt this.

The code I have been trying to use is here:

```
<?php
    $servername = "ns303998.ip-x-x-x.eu";
    $username = "x";
    $password = "x";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

The database name is the issue. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Confirm via MySQL command line client that you can connect remotely before you involve PHP, your MySQL configuration may be blocking the connection.

Comment: If the database is on a shared server, the hosting provider might need you or your friend to add a IP address range that allows remote access to it. Most cases they don't by default allow direct connections from sites that aren't on their hosting servers

Comment: Thank you, let me look into that.

Comment: If the database is on a shared server, the hosting provider might need you or your friend to add a IP address range that allows remote access to it. Most cases they don't by default allow direct connections from sites that aren't on their hosting servers

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_connect takes 4 arguments, not 3 as you are trying. The fourth one is database name. Documentation is [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php).

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Edit: The argument is optional, but if it's is a shared hosting, your credentials are probably working for the one specific database, not the whole server. So specifying the database could help you with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_connect needs database name to execute

```
<?php
$servername = "ns303998.ip-x-x-x.eu";
$username = "x";
$password = "x";
$dbname ="x";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

$dbname='yourdbname';

mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);

to select the database